# Relays or MOSFETs

Tags: arduino, mosfet, batteries, relay, mosfet-driver

I’m making a circuit with peltier modules, a relay H-bridge and an Arduino. The system takes input from user of desired temperature. There is a temperature sensor placed on the peltier and the system reads the output from the sensor and decides to give either hot or cold, depending on the desired temperature.

I need more current to power the peltier than I have at the moment, and right now I have 2 relays which switch polarity connected to a battery and the module.

As I said, **I need more current**. Should I connect more batteries in parallel or should I switch to a MOSFET H-bridge motor driver instead of the relays? (I've been told that MOSFETs amplify current signal) and if so, which driver do people recommend?

Comment: MOSFETs don't amplify current. If the relays can't handle the current or the battery does not give enough current then MOSFETs don't help. The resistance of relay contacts are approximatey similar level with MOSFET on resistance.

Comment: A MOSFET amplifies current in the sense that it *controls* a large current using a very small current. It still doesn't make current out of thin air.

Answer (score 2):

> (I´ve been told that MOSFETs amplify current signal)

Not true. MOSFETs do not amplify current. However, a buck DC converter, often implemented with MOSFETs, can output more current than is input. As it steps the input voltage down, it can step up the current, always drawing more power (VxI) than it supplies.

Note that for best efficiency, a Peltier should be operated with clean DC, as from a filtered buck converter, not PWM. This holds whether the PWM is fast, as in 'stepping down the average current with kHz switching', or slow, as in 'on/off cycles of seconds or even minutes to control the temperature'. The heat transport is proportional to the average current, and the heat generated within the Peltier itself is proportional to current squared. This ratio is minimised with clean DC. Implement a PID loop to drive the buck converter to give your Peltier exactly the right voltage.

Answer (score 1):

> *Should I connect more batteries in parallel or should I switch to a
> MOSFET H-bridge motor driver instead of the relays? (I´ve been told
> that MOSFETs amplify current signal) and if so, which driver do people
> recommend?*

A MOSFET cannot extra "magic" current from nowhere. The power supply has to be able to deliver the current to the MOSFET (then to the load) in the first place. More batteries in parallel is a typical approach but then you might need some form of battery management system. Bigger replacement batteries with more current delivery is the simple answer.

> *which driver do people recommend*

Device recommendation questions are off-topic on this site.

Answer (score 0):

A normal bipolar transistor let the current flow, maybe you let 1mA flow into the base and 100 times of this current can flow through the collector.
But the current must be delivered by the power supply.

What you need is a Step-Down Voltage regulator.

Basically you give him 12 Volt and you want only 1 Volt and 6A of output-current, then you need 12V and 0.5A input-current.

You can get these types of Step-Down converters cheap on eBay or Aliexpress. Take a look at the current ratings.

The LT3800 StepDown-Converter with external MosFETs:
https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/3800fc.pdf

Examples:
https://de.aliexpress.com/item/33001457183.html
https://de.aliexpress.com/item/32916731611.html
https://de.aliexpress.com/item/32833317118.html

You can connect the Peltier-Elements in line, to increase the voltage which is needed.

Which type of Peltier-Element modules do you use?
Which type of Energy source do you have there?